# Magento 2.3.3 Sales / Orders / View is missing vital information

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

When upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 from 2.3.2, the Sales / Orders / View, does no longer show:

- Order & account Information
- Adress Information,

It looks like it has something to do with a module called Medma\Disableregistration\, it was not compatible with 2.3.3, so I uninstalled it, but for some reason it still shows up.

Now when trying to look at Sales / Order / View, it get this info:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Medma\Disableregistration\Model\Config\Source\Options does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Medma\Disableregistration\Model\Config\Source\Options does not exist
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Medma\Disablereg...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]

## 2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Medma\Disablereg...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]

## 3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Medma\Disablereg...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]

## 4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Medma\Disablereg...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]

## 5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('Medma\Disablereg...') called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]

## 6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AttributeMetadataConverter.php:68]

## 7

But the Medma\Disableregistration does not show up anywhere, when I search for it, not in app/code, and it is also removed from the Database as far as I have been able to see.

Comment: Remove the `generated` folder also, and check in the code if is there any dependency on this class added. and one more thing check in `eav-attribute` this module may have any `eav-attribute` created in the database that needed to be removed.